# Safari4 HTML5 Socket support

Tags: html, mobile, safari, websocket

I've heard that HTML5 will support open sockets. Does anyone know if it's currently supported in Safari 4? I'm particularly interested in getting sockets to work through the Safari browser of an iPhone.

Thanks in advance,
Josh

Answer (score 0):

Web Sockets were not supported in [Safari 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253683/). An iPhone with [iOS 4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574385/) or above includes Web Sockets support in mobile Safari. Check the following page for future reference:

- [Web Sockets support chart](http://caniuse.com/websockets)