# Do I need a server to use HTML5's WebSockets?

Tags: html, websocket

When using WebSockets, will I need to write server code? In other words, will the JavaScript in my client application need to connect to a specialized server, or will my existing Apache server work to support this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The server has to support web sockets. After a first handshake in HTTP, the server and the client open a socket connection. The server must be able to understand and accept this handshake.

In my last project we run quite successfully web socket connections using the last Jetty version.

27/02/2014:
Now I'm also implementing websockets under .net with XSockets.net and works like a charm, you don't even need a web server (self hosting). The WebSocket implementation of ASP.NET works also quite good.

Comment: cwebsocket on github is a nice small server. it's easy to be expanded it into also a http server.

Answer (score 7):

Yes,you need to write server code.

I recommend another web socket server based on php: [ratchet](https://github.com/cboden/Ratchet).
And this [link](http://www.cargomedia.ch/websocket/benchmarking-websocket-servers/) is benchmarking webSocket servers between ratchet and sockJS.

Complete list of client & server side codes and browsers support please check this [**link**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2700609/1567114)

Answer (score 5):

Of course you need a WebSocket server. But there are many free websocket server in different language, like jWebSocket in Java and [SuperWebSocket](http://superwebsocket.codeplex.com) in .NET, you can use them directly.

Comment: Why do you say "of course" you need a server? It could operate peer-to-peer, no?

Comment: @JonathanStark no. Websocket are client/server only. they are not peer to peer. For peer to peer solution check the webrtc spec.

Comment: My bad. Was thinking of WebRTC. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 5):

There are some plugins currently being developed on google code for Apache...

By definition websockets like normal sockets are client-server so yes, you need a server. However there is an alternative to waiting for Apache plugins.

I am using a hosted server http://www.achex.ca. Its free and you have tutorials in javascript on how to use the server. A good start for websockets development.

The server is basically a message router and you can connect to it and use it as a meeting point for all your websocket clients.

**Short Answer**: **Yes**, You need a specialized server, Apache does not come with websockets.
OR
 **The alternative**, check out [www.achex.ca](http://www.achex.ca).

Answer (score 3):

In such a situation the role of server comes when :

In HTML 5,WebSocket like a fone(2-way comm.) not walky-talky.
http protocol upgraded to websocket protocol.**`(wss:// from ws://)`**
SERVER should be able to open duplex channel and hence AGREE with duplex communication.

Please go through this link : http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/

If using php please look at RATCHET.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The Perl Mojolicious server supports web sockets, and implementations can be only a few lines long.

Node.js has several WebSocket libraries but details of the latest, greatest, most supportive of the latest spec vary, so choose carefully.

Apache Active MQ is also worth a look, along with the stomp protocol it implements.