# How to Use Sockets in JavaScript\HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, websocket

How to Use Sockets in JavaScript\HTML?

May be using some cool HTML5?

Libraries?
Tutorials?
Blog Articles?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Which browser do you want to support?

Comment: I assume you are refering to Web Sockets

Comment: Do you mean TCP sockets?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Specifications:

- [Web Sockets API](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/web-sockets.html#network)

Articles:

- [HTML5 WebSocket and WebJneering](http://svwebbuilder.wordpress.com/2008/10/20/html5-websocket-and-webjneering/)

Tutorial:

- [HTML5 Rocks - WebSockets](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/)

Libraries:

- Check this SO post [html5 websocket
  need server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1530023/html5-websocket-need-server), it links to
  https://kaazing.com/download

Comment: Update: `bobince` provided a simple tutorial on this page :P

Comment: Yes, that user would presumably be Kaazing's own Jonas Jacobi. Often pops up anywhere WebSocket is mentioned! I don't quite get Kaazing TBH, sitting on websocket.org to promote what appears to be a monolithic not-actually-free client-and-server solution that has has WebSocket support as seemingly quite a small portion of what it actually does. I don't know, It might be a good solution, but I'm not wholly comfortable with the marketing really. [edited, hence after okw's reply]

Answer (score 79):

> How to Use Sockets in JavaScript/HTML?

There is no facility to use general-purpose sockets in JS or HTML. It would be a security disaster, for one.

There is WebSocket in HTML5. The client side is fairly trivial:

```
socket= new WebSocket('ws://www.example.com:8000/somesocket');
socket.onopen= function() {
    socket.send('hello');
};
socket.onmessage= function(s) {
    alert('got reply '+s);
};
```

You will need a specialised socket application on the server-side to take the connections and do something with them; it is not something you would normally be doing from a web server's scripting interface. However it is a [relatively simple protocol](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-hixie-thewebsocketprotocol); my noddy Python SocketServer-based endpoint was only a couple of pages of code.

In any case, it doesn't really exist, yet. Neither the JavaScript-side spec nor the network transport spec are nailed down, and no browsers support it.

You can, however, use Flash where available to provide your script with a fallback until WebSocket is widely available. Gimite's [web-socket-js](http://github.com/gimite/web-socket-js) is one free example of such. However you are subject to the same limitations as Flash Sockets then, namely that your server has to be able to spit out a cross-domain policy on request to the socket port, and you will often have difficulties with proxies/firewalls. (Flash sockets are made directly; for someone without direct public IP access who can only get out of the network through an HTTP proxy, they won't work.)

Unless you really need low-latency two-way communication, you are better off sticking with `XMLHttpRequest` for now.

Comment: What kinds of WS bindings will html5 support?

Comment: If you mean what will WebSocket objects look like in the browser, it still remains to be seen, but the spec (http://www.w3.org/TR/websockets/) hasn't changed a lot recently. If by WS Bindings you're talking about Web Services, then none: WebSocket won't talk SOAP or any other pre-existing protocol.

Comment: You say "There is no facility to use general-purpose sockets in JS or HTML. It would be a security disaster, for one." but what about phonegap or phonegap related applications? HTML+js  is not just needed for standart browsers.

Answer (score 47):

I think it is important to mention, now that this question is over 1 year old, that [Socket.IO](http://socket.io/) has since come out and seems to be the primary way to work with sockets in the browser now; it is also compatible with [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/) as far as I know.

Comment: OK. It's been almost 6 years. Have the standards changed?