# 2 player game connecting without using Flash / Silverlight

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

How can I possibly connect the players? How can I add a window wherein they can see each other like on the Tetris battle on Facebook?

I know some basic ajax polling. I am developing a Chess game.

Can this be possible on using jQuery/JavaScript?

Can anyone help me? I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using Web Sockets (an html5 feature).

Here's more info: [How to Use Sockets in JavaScript\HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1736382/how-to-use-sockets-in-javascript-html)

And here's a cool library that uses it with a flash backup ( in case someone doesnt have an html5 browser)

http://socket.io/#faq

Comment: Hey Flash fallback =) Websockets are fun.

Comment: Flash isn't the only fallback that Socket.IO can use: http://socket.io/#browser-support

Comment: +1 for socket.io. It does require node.js, but personally I find node.js a convenient environment to work in, more than PHP.

Comment: well, PHP is dead easy..where node.js requires a long learning-curve. I don't think it's worth learning just to socket communications. Things like this should take a day or two tops to make, not a month of boring study.

Answer (score 2):

Use [WebSockets](http://websocket.org/). You will maybe need server-side JavaScript so use [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) for that.

Comment: In no way does WebSockets require server-side JavaScript. It does require a server which somehow supports WebSockets.

Comment: No but it requires a modern browser.

Comment: And there are flash fallbacks for Websockets. Sweeet! You don't need Node, but it is very easy to use for Websockets. PHP for example isn't.

Answer (score 0):

You included "mySql" in your tags.  You could also use the "database" to communicate:

1. Each "game" adds a new row
2. A player's "move" updates the database (e.g. via an Ajax message)

Comment: This might be slow, but it's still an interesting idea.