# How to edit the contents of a file on button click? PHP?

Tags: javascript, php

**number.txt**:

```
1
```

**index.php**:

```
<?php
$handle = file_get_contents("number.txt");    
?>

    <form action="" method="post">
    <button class="click"></button>
    </form>
```

How would I make it so that when the user clicks on the button, the file **number.txt** gets edited so that it changes from 1 to 2? And then to 3, 4, 5 and so on?

Clicking on the button would increase the number by one

Let's say I clicked on the button, if I open up **number.txt**, I would now see:

```
2
```

Just to reiterate, there is a file called **number.txt** and that file has the contents "1" (without the quotes). Now, on the **index.php** page, there is a *form* containing a *button* within. Once you click on the *button*, **numbers.txt** file will be rewritten so that its value goes up by one (each time the button is clicked) - in this case, the file **number.txt** will now have the contents "2" (without the quotes).

I am not  quite sure how I would do this, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is a little short on information. Can you share what you have tried, and what problems have you run into?

Comment: PHP: fopen fwrite :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into form submitting and handling files (either via `fopen/fwrite/fclose` or via `file_get_contents/file_put_contents`). This is the functionality you described above:

```
<h2>Click</h2>
<form action="" method="post">
    <button name="click" class="click">Click me!</button>
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['click']))
{
    $filename = "number.txt";
    $before_editing = file_get_contents($filename);
    echo "Content of the file " . $filename . " before editing: " . $before_editing . "<br>";
    file_put_contents($filename, "2");
    $after_editing = file_get_contents($filename);
    echo "Content of the file " . $filename . " after editing: " . $after_editing . "<br>";
}
?>
```

Notice that once you run this script, the contents of the file `number.txt` gets rewritten to "2". You'll have to edit it again manually to see some changes.

---

Based on the change in the question, this is the code that will increment the number value each time the button gets clicked:

```
<h2>Click</h2>
<form action="" method="post">
    <button name="click" class="click">Click me!</button>
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['click']))
{
    $filename = "number.txt";
    $content = file_get_contents($filename);
    preg_match("#\d+#", $content, $before_editing);
    $number_before = $before_editing[0];
    echo "The number in " . $filename . " before clicking: " . $number_before . "<br>";

    file_put_contents($filename, ++$number_before);

    $content = file_get_contents($filename);
    preg_match("#\d+#", $content, $after_editing);
    $number_after = $after_editing[0];
    echo "The number in " . $filename . " after clicking: " . $number_after . "<br>";
}
?>
```