# Ending a shell_exec process PHP

Tags: php, apache, shell-exec

been trying to figure this one out for a couple of hours now. No luck.

I am trying to build a system that can run reports (running scripts in the background) using shell_exec.

The following code starts the script that runs the report:
`shell_exec("php /var/www/html/lab-40/test/invoice_reminder.php");`

Now how would I go about ending that script execution using PHP?

I've tried things like PIDS but I have no clue how I would go about this. Thanks for the help in advance!

EDIT: I am not trying to end the process if the e.g tab is closed.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to force end it?

Comment: So from a web-based control panel, lets say the user wants to cancel running the report

Comment: Check out this [comment](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php#59898) on `shell_exec` help page.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP shell\_exec - how to terminate the process if the connection is closed?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16103650/10967889)

Comment: @daksh I don't want the script to be killed upon the tab being closed.

Comment: @user3724476 `shell_exec('kill -KILL ProcessID');` this might help

Comment: @Furgas Thanks for that. With actually getting the PID I assume it's this part of the shell_exec that gets it "& echo $!".

Comment: For better control of child processes, take a look át [PCNTL Functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pcntl.php) and [POSIX Functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.posix.php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on this [comment](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php#59898) on shell_exec help page (`&` will bring the process to the background, and `echo $!` will print the process PID):

```
<?php

function shell_exec_background(string $command): int {
    return (int)shell_exec(
        sprintf(
            'nohup %s 1> /dev/null 2> /dev/null & echo $!',
            $command
        )
    );
}

function is_pid_running(int $pid): bool {
    exec(
        sprintf(
            'kill -0 %d 1> /dev/null 2> /dev/null',
            $pid
        ),
        $output,
        $exit_code
    );

    return $exit_code === 0;
}

function kill_pid(int $pid): bool {
    exec(
        sprintf(
            'kill -KILL %d 1> /dev/null 2> /dev/null',
            $pid
        ),
        $output,
        $exit_code
    );

    return $exit_code === 0;
}

$pid = shell_exec_background('php /var/www/html/lab-40/test/invoice_reminder.php');
var_dump($pid);
var_dump(is_pid_running($pid));
var_dump(kill_pid($pid));
```