# Client server communication over hosted network

Tags: python, django, sockets, networking

Okay I'm a bit new to network programming. We have a site running over a hosted network with a static IP. We want to send some information to the client's PC who connects or logs into the website. Normal sockets are not working as we're getting an error 'refusing connections'. The sockets work in the same subnet but not over internet. How do we connect to the client's computer via server. Are there any libraries for that? Plus the server needs to serve multiple clients who are connected.

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1736382/how-to-use-sockets-in-javascript-html

Comment: Do you want to connect  from the server to the client? There should be no need to do so. Every connection can be used to send and receive. Let the client connect to he server.