# Can you use normal sockets in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, sockets

It seems that every question about *sockets* and *Javascript* results to an answer to use WebSockets. OK, I get that. I know you can't use sockets because of the [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

**BUT**. Are sockets just non-existent from the browser or do they exist and just happen to be limited?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1736422/965907

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Use Sockets in JavaScript\HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1736382/how-to-use-sockets-in-javascript-html)

Comment: @Rhumborl and again everyone is sending me to Websockets..

Comment: Top-rated answer from the duplicate starts with: `There is no facility to use general-purpose sockets in JS or HTML. It would be a security disaster, for one.` I didn't send you to WebSockets, you just asked the same question

Comment: @Rhumborl Sometimes you have to read behind the lines. That guy just looks for a fast hack. I am wondering if **normal** sockets exist.

Answer (score 0):

There is a working draft on [TCP/UDP sockets](http://www.w3.org/TR/raw-sockets/), previously referred to as the "Raw Socket API."

[This library](https://github.com/whiteout-io/tcp-socket) implements it.  I have not tested it personally, but it's probably what you're looking for.