# Auto-complete search, is there a way to code auto complete search without using php?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, search, autocomplete

I only plan to use html, mysql, javascript and jquery.

I know learning php will be a great help in the future but it will take me too long to learn everything in a week.

For the sever side I use servlets..

Thank you

Comment: If you want to do auto-complete from the list which stored in the Database, you have to use any of a server side language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found third party plug ins to do this

devbrige,
intellesense,
jquery auto complete

http://www.techyari.in/2014/04/jquery-autocomplete-ajax-tutorial-j2ee-json-mysql.html

https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete

though I am still trying to work the codes out

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, no. Well, strictly speaking, you don't need PHP, but you will need some server-side technology.

Assuming the data you need to autocomplete exists in mySQL, and you use `jQuery.ajax()` or similar to get the information on the fly, you still need some data access layer in between, which is where PHP or similar comes in. Of course, if you're accessing data that has been exposed by an API, you might have better luck.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL runs on your server, but the browser can't open a socket directly to it to do queries. See: [How to Use Sockets in JavaScript\HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1736382/383793)

So you will need something on the server that talks to MySQL and responds back to your jQuery code. I'm all with you that you don't want to learn PHP. If you already know javascript, you can use [node.js](/questions/tagged/node.js) on the server. It has libraries to talk to MySQL: [MySQL with Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818312/mysql-with-node-js)

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to connect to your mySQL database directly using Javascript running on the client. The only possible way I can imagine is using another database system which offers an HTTP-interface (such as Apache Cassandra) or using a plugin for mySQL which does this job (I could not find an officially supported one, maybe you got more luck). This way, you could query data using Javascript/Ajax directly from your client.

But keep attention to security concerns, such as SQL injections or handling of client connections, which gets much more complex if you are not using a middle tier (PHP, nodejs, Java, etc.) running on a web server.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use any server side technology for autocomplete. Without  using any server side technology you can't create autocomplete (you can do it by adding some dummy records)