# Displaying indication that "user typing..." in conversation of websystems

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, angularjs

I saw this many of web pages such as Facebook , Google Hangouts (i'm taking about in conversation between tow people). When one user type his message on text box, that is indicate on destination user's conversation box like GIF animation. When i saw this for first, I also try it. But i'm not be able to got that. I was look this interaction with my browser's developer tool so I can see change the class of GIF animation div. I think it might be used onkeyup javascript event. How do that? Is it possible that trigger javascript event another computer or another page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the information has to go through a server, that sends back the event to the other browsers, which then display "user typing...".

This event is mostly seen on chat modules in websites, who are built using sockets.
See this post: [How to Use Sockets in JavaScript\HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1736382/how-to-use-sockets-in-javascript-html#answer-1736398)

Comment: Can i do that in my appachi(php) localhost?

Comment: No, or it is going to be prety hard (I actually never tried doing sockets in PHP). Try making a `Node.js` server