# Request to refresh a page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, refresh

i am at this moment stuck with a problem :

Let's say there is two computers : A, and B.

We do "post request" and "insert in mysql database" with computer A.

I want to refresh a page on computer B (or better, a div with Ajax), when my tables in my database are updated.

The easiest but worst solution that i found is to do a select in the database with a counter, every X seconds for exemple and refresh the page of B if the counter is higher than X secondes before.

I'm working on this project in php, javascript, and jQuery.

How can i do that ? I want a good solution, but quickly realisable.

Thanks !

(Computer A and Computer B aren't in the same page)

Comment: Computer A and B are on the same page, then when Computer A Insert data. You want the computer B to see the data inserted without reloading the page? Am i right?

Comment: XMLHttpRequest is ajax - it makes one asynchronous HTTP request. Websockets keep an open connection and messages can be sent in both directions. They aren't the same thing and so one is not better than the other, it's comparing apples to oranges.

Comment: Genina, no they are in two different pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have your clients keep a socket connection open with the server. socket connections stay open and you can send messages back and forth. When the table is updated on the server, broadcast a message out and then have the client side listen for that message, and refresh the table.

Some good links on sockets in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1736398/1879895

Comment: Cool! If you decide that my answer helped, please give it an upvote and/or mark it as correct! Thanks!

Comment: Not enought reputation mate :(

Comment: As you asked the question you should be able to mark a correct answer - there should be a grey tick next to the answer?