# WinSock2 javascript client side

Tags: javascript, html, c++

I have a server side using sockets (WinSock2 lib),
How do I implement a C++ client side socket and make a connection with JavaScript?
I want the client side to be an HTML, CSS and etc with JavaScript.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: Can't you just google this yourself, there's probably 500 sites with tutorials on this stuff. Try W3 maybe!

Comment: Havent found this on google

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Use Sockets in JavaScript\HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1736382/how-to-use-sockets-in-javascript-html)

Comment: Yeah, I searched too. The only kind of coding you could do is a mix of AJAX and maybe PHP besides that winsock 2 would need to be a plugin. You would need to code winsock 2 in C++ and somehow "attach" that to your browser as a plug in. Interfacing the Javascript code with that is probably the best option.

Comment: @YardenLevin Which search phrases did you use?

Comment: @rafaelcastrocouto thanks for the link, didn't know about HTML5 having that till now. Cheers!