# HTML5 Sockets/Multiplayer

Tags: html

I have just started HTML5 game development, I made a couple of games using the canvas, accessing it with Javascript.

I wonder, though, about how I can make multiplayer online games. Do I necessarily need to use server side stuff for this?

I've heard of HTML5 Sockets, are there other alternatives?

Thank you.

EDIT: Any simple example or links are very much appreciated.

Comment: I think http://browserquest.mozilla.org/ is a good example. Source code: https://github.com/mozilla/BrowserQuest

Comment: http://www.multiplayerpiano.com/ is something I'd love to see the source code of, it uses socket.io.

Comment: @user996058 I posted an early version of the multiplayerpiano.com server:  https://gist.github.com/1775362 -- it's really just dead simple :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a server, P2P doesn't work yet between browsers. See: [Do I need a server to use HTML5's WebSockets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1530023/do-i-need-a-server-to-use-html5s-websockets)

Websocket (HTML5 sockets) is a way to have a bi-directional open connection between the browser and your server. Otherwise you'll have to work using XHR (aka Ajax) which is pull only. Mozilla wrote a great article explaining how they built: [BrowserQuest](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/03/browserquest/) (or just play it: http://browserquest.mozilla.org/)

Alternatives are generally based on *Flash XMLSocket*!

Comment: I do have a server, FTP server where I host my files, I'm guessing that's enough, right?

Comment: you have to run a command in a console to start a socket.io server as far as I know.

Comment: @user996056 nope, you need a specific web server. One that can accept web sockets (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_WebSocket_implementations)