# Updating page with database information

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to make a refresh algorithm for my site but dont want to have a bunch of `$.post()` scripts being sent to the server checking for updates. So I was wondering if there were any good ways of sending updates to the page that is being viewed when something on a database is changed.

Comment: Just cause there is no question mark does not mean that its not a question....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The common way to do it is called [*Comet*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29).

Basically, you create an `XMLHttpRequest`, send it to the server and wait. The server keeps the connection open, and sends data then closes it each time something happens server-side. It can also send nothing and close every 30 seconds or so to clean up things a bit.

*WebSockets* are a rather new technology, and it will be the way to go in the future, but I encourage you to use *Comet* right now, unless you want to play with something that's a little on the bleeding-edge side of web developement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use html5 web-sockets

You need a server, P2P doesn't work yet between browsers. See: [Do I need a server to use HTML5's WebSockets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1530023/do-i-need-a-server-to-use-html5s-websockets)

Websocket (HTML5 sockets) is a way to have a bi-directional open connection between the browser and your server. Otherwise you'll have to work using XHR (aka Ajax) which is pull only. Mozilla wrote a great article explaining how they built: BrowserQuest (or just play it: http://browserquest.mozilla.org/)

Alternatives are generally based on Flash XMLSocket!

Comment: Actually, XHR and Comet are common technologies for push nowadays.

Comment: can you please elaborate on that @F.X.