# Is "long polling" the most efficient way to create a Web Real Time App?

Tags: javascript, flash, streaming, comet, long-polling

I want to create an application like this:

http://collabedit.com/

What is the most efficient way to create this real time application?

Flash? Long polling? Http Streaming? or something else?

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For now, long polling is probably the best solution.  Many big-name sites have long polling implementations, including Facebook, Google and eBay.  Not everyone has Flash installed/enabled in their browsers.  In the future [Web Sockets](http://www.barklund.org/blog/2009/08/20/web-sockets-html-5-solve-http-pull/) might be able to do an easier job of it for us.

**Update:** As of this writing, the [WebSocket API](http://dev.w3.org/html5/websockets/) is implemented in the latest WebKit (Chrome/Safari) and Firefox 4 beta.  There is also a public snapshot build of Opera [available for download](http://my.opera.com/desktopteam/blog/2010/10/11/websockets) with an implementation of the API.  This means testing the API is widely available.  For more information, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253683/websocket-for-html5/1253730#1253730).

Comment: +1 I like long polling. The future might be different but I wouldn't go with Flash.

Comment: I have used phpfreechat ( that use long polling ) and with only 20 people is very very very slow !! Why ?
I need to create a real time app for million of people simultanely !!

Comment: @xRobot: Have you checked the FAQ? [http://www.phpfreechat.net/faq] It offers a solution for one performance issue related to disk access.  Other than that you require a very high powered server to handle millions of connections at the same time.  Normal http requests are open->get data->close, so simultaneous connections are fewer.  With long polling it's open->wait for data->close, so many simultaneous are almost guaranteed.  Servers can only handle a limited amount of concurrent connections, and you get what you pay for, if you catch my drift!

Comment: I don't think Google use Long-Poll to implement Comet. At least, GMail implements comet with XHR-streaming.

Comment: @Morgan Cheng: Right you are. I heard that XHR-streaming was problematic with Internet Explorer, but it appears Google found a way around that. http://alex.dojotoolkit.org/2006/02/what-else-is-burried-down-in-the-depths-of-googles-amazing-javascript/

Comment: +1, the best way to do that's completely cross-browser is long-polling, which is implemented in a number of comet servers. The hack mentioned for gtalk is htmlfile streaming, which is different and has its own limitations: http://cometdaily.com/2007/11/18/ie-activexhtmlfile-transport-part-ii/

Comment: While recent webkit might support it, old infrastructure appliances in the middle might still block the WS protocol. It's reasonable to consider falling back on xhr-polling.

Answer (score 4):

All the different methods have different pros and cons, I'm not an specialist on the differences, that's why I'll recomend you to **avoid making the choice**, avoid the development and tuning that each approach involves, avoid the future changes in available technologies (ie. as HTML5 web sockets arrival), using a library that **abstracts the transport method used**, and chooses the best approach based on client capabilities:

http://socket.io/

this wonderful library makes creating realtime apps amazingly simple! and there are various server-side implementations: Python (Tornado), Java, Google GO, Rack (Ruby), besides the mainstream implementation in Node.js (server-side JavaScript)

Comment: Yup..!! Already used it with both Java and NodeJS. its brillient tool. For java we can use netty server implementation.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think long-polling is most efficient way to do Comet. Anyway, it sends new HTTP request after response is got. It cost more extra HTTP requests than HTTP streaming.

But, long-polling might be more reliable and easier to implement than HTTP streaming. According to this [article in Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-incubator/wiki/ServerPushFAQ), HTTP streaming might not be functional if intermediate HTTP proxy buffers content.

It is interesting that GMail doesn't use long-polling. With the help of Http sniffer, it is clear that it uses HTTP streaming for Comet.

Comment: Also Facebook don't use long polling ? Do you know any example for http streaming ? Thans ^_^

Comment: I haven't test it personally, but I'm told that Facebook chat is implemented by long-polling.

GMail is Http Streaming. So is Outlook Web Access.

Comment: @xRobot, if you are looking forward to how-to, this URL is a good summary： http://cometdaily.com/2007/12/11/the-future-of-comet-part-1-comet-today/