# websockets protocols?

Tags: html, udp, websocket, udpclient, rudp

I couldn't find this online so I thought I'd ask here.

What protocols can be used by websockets currently? (in chrome)

Also does chrome or any other browser plan to support RUDP protocol for websockets eventually?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WebSocket **is** the protocol. See the [Internet-Draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-hixie-thewebsocketprotocol-76). And it's not using UDP.

Comment: Technically Websockets would be part of the application layer, UDP the transport protocol.

Comment: @tadman: From the linked Draft: `The protocol consists of an initial
   handshake followed by basic message framing, layered over TCP.`

Answer (score 2):

[What browsers support HTML5 WebSocket API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253683/websocket-for-html5)

http://blog.chromium.org/2009/12/web-sockets-now-available-in-google.html

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-hixie-thewebsocketprotocol-55

Also of note, it appears someone created a Flash WebSockets proxy so you can extend your clientbase to anyone with Flash, as well as existing Chrome users.