# Html5 Websockets - What should I know about sockets before using websockets

Tags: sockets, html

I'm currently experimenting with html5 and websockets.
I know next to nothing about "ordinary" sockets. Before messing about with websockets I think it might be wise to learn about sockets.
Is there any online material that I should read or excersizes that I should go through to get myself up to speed? 
It might be worth pointing out that I'm a c# programmer mainly.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

The short answer: nothing.  The WebSocket protocol is a high-level (layer-7) protocol; the normal "sockets" that I think you're referring to are TCP sockets, which are much more low-level, and are programmed using the Berkeley sockets API.  If you just want to use the WebSocket protocol on a pragmatic level, all you need to learn is the simple Javascript API for dealing with the same.

Answer (score 0):

Well, surely you must read this at first. [Browsers that support web-socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253683/websocket-for-html5)