# is it too early to use the websockets?

Tags: javascript, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [WebSocket for HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253683/websocket-for-html5)

Hello,

I would like to use http://dev.w3.org/html5/websockets/

can I start or is it too early and no browser support it yet

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

At the present time you can use something like [socket.io](http://socket.io/) library to provide fallback for browsers which don't support WebSocket functionality. Flash sockets or long polling will be used instead.