# Web socket server for Windows or Ubuntu 9.04

Tags: websocket

Where can I download websocket server for Windows. Easy to install. Different from node.js I have already tried this one and couldn't manage to run it on my computer.

Comment: Here are a lot of suggestions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253683/websocket-for-html5.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are developing for Windows you'll probably be using .NET. Here are a few .NET WebSocket server options (I'll also be updating this [realtime technologies guide](http://www.leggetter.co.uk/real-time-technologies-guide) with tech as I find them).

- [XSockets](http://xsockets.net/)
- [SuperWebSocket](http://superwebsocket.codeplex.com/)
- [WebSync](http://www.frozenmountain.com/websync/) (which works with IIS)
- [Pokein](http://pokein.com/)

Comment: I use javascript. I don't have host name but I won't need one since this app should be something like desktop app.