# Where can I find list of web browsers for ubuntu that maintain web sockets (different from Chrome)?

Tags: browser, websocket, ubuntu-9.04

I need a webkit browser for ubuntu 9.04 that maintain web sockets. I know that Chrome maintain web sockets but I couldn't install Chrome on i.mx51.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the current list of browsers that support WebSockets and the protocol version they support: [What browsers support HTML5 WebSocket API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253683/websocket-for-html5)

If you have Flash available you can use [web-socket-js](https://github.com/gimite/web-socket-js) which is a shim/polyfill that adds WebSockets support to any browser.