# Building a whole website using websockets? Revisited

Tags: performance, http, websocket, http-headers

So this question has been asked four years ago, when websockets weren't supported by many browsers back in 2011 here 
-> [Build a whole site using just websockets (via socket.io and node.js, no Ajax)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8041710/build-a-whole-site-using-just-websockets-via-socket-io-and-node-js-no-ajax)

And with the reduction of the size of http headers websockets provide and four years of further development since that question has been asked, would a website build only with websockets help performance and network latency with smaller headers? the initial handshake would occur during a login phase and the connection would timeout after a time period or during logout. So once again, would a website, social network, with real time chat or push notifications benefit from being built solely out of websockets vs http?

Comment: webSocket vs. Ajax are a tradeoff that depends upon the usage scenario.  If you're making regular and frequent and constant ajax-like calls from client to server, then you may well benefit from having a continuous connection with a webSocket.  But, if the client usage is sporadic and not constant, then it may be less scalable and more complicated to maintain continuous TCP connections to a large number of clients than it is to process temporal ajax calls.  A websocket connection is less efficient to initiate (it starts with an http connection), but more efficient to use once established.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Real time chat and push notifications are a good candidate for websockets, and it is quite possible they scale better than ajax. See this question:
[Do HTML WebSockets maintain an open connection for each client? Does this scale?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4852702/do-html-websockets-maintain-an-open-connection-for-each-client-does-this-scale)

Just don't needlessly force every functionality of your website to fit into your websockets-centric architecture if ajax is a better solution in that situation.