# HTTP/2 vs web-sockets for bidirectional message streaming

Tags: websocket, grpc, http2, server-sent-events

Besides for browsers, which do not expose HTTP/2 frames to Javascript, in what case would Websockets be a better choice than something like bidirectional streaming gRPCs (built on HTTP/2) for implementing real-time bidirectional message streams? Also, doesn't HTTP 2.0 being full-duplex (and bidirectional) mean that server pushes are in fact supported? What is the need for something like SSE, then? This is made obsolete, right?

Comment: Also check https://stackoverflow.com/a/42465368/520567

Answer (score 15):

There is many aspects here. Server Sent Events, JavaScript Streams API is mostly browser APIs for lower level protocols.

## Server to Server communication

Server to Server communication using Websockets and HTTP/2 has similar properties. Both are binary and efficient protocols. HTTP/2 provides per stream backpressure which can be important for clients that receives push messages from multiple sources or may be busy at times. gRPC is a framework on top of HTTP/2 and provides a higher abstraction to the developer.

## Server to Browser communication

### Server Sent Events

[Server Sent Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events) is a way for a client to subscribe to an event stream and continuously receive events from a server. The API is a higher abstraction and easier to use than alternatives. However the format is a specified message format in **text**.

> Developing a web application that uses server-sent events is easier than with websockets. You'll need a bit of code on the server to stream events to the front-end, but the client side code works almost identically to handling any other event.

Example code

```
const evtSource = new EventSource("/v1/stream/topic");

evtSource.onmessage = function(event) {
   // handle event
}
```

### JavaScript Streams API

[JavaScript Streams API](https://streams.spec.whatwg.org/) is a newer JavaScript API for supporting binary streams between browser and server. This can be used with the newer [ReadableStream](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStream) from [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API). Since this is a binary stream, it can have a broader use case and may be important for applications using e.g. webassembly in upcoming years.

The API is a bit more complex. Example code:

```
fetch("https://www.example.org/").then((response) => {
  const reader = response.body.getReader();
  const stream = new ReadableStream({
    start(controller) {
       // implementation
    }
  })
```

The advantage with a binary stream is that it may be used for naturally binary data e.g. audio or binary respresentations of custom formats.

Using JavaScript Streams API on HTTP/2 or HTTP/3 Streams has the advantage over alternatives in that it supports *backpressure* per stream (not only per TCP connection).

### gRPC

gRPC is a protocol using HTTP/2 streams, but it is not implemented on the JavaScript Streams API, so for browser communication it needs some middleware like [grpc-web](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-web).

### WebSockets

WebSockets is a lower level abstraction and it has broader browser support and it supports full-duplex communication. But since it is a lower level abstraction it often requires libraries to handle the communication.

Comment: Sorry, maybe a stpid question, but what do you mean with "backpressure"?

Comment: ... and, should we add SignalR in this, as a commonly used abstraction on top of WebSockets?

Comment: @ohnezahn I had the same question and found this link useful: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Streams_API/Concepts#backpressure