# If websockets are obsolete then what is the replacement?

Tags: websocket, socket.io, signalr, http2

Many resources including this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28582935/does-http-2-make-websockets-obsolete) suggest that after the introduction of HTTP/2, websockets became obsolete mainly due to the bidirectional communication mechanism in HTTP/2. But the question is that what is then the replacement? I have been looking into a few new features in the HTTP protocol such as the Server Push and Streaming and I found them to be quite irrelevant to the problem that the websocket is addressing.

I would like add another point to my question which is that, if websockets are obsolete, does it mean that SocketIO, SignalR, Pusher, etc. are also obsolete as a result? If no, then what do they use under the hood? (Except for long polling)

Comment: I don't believe the SignalR is obsolete because of the fact that Microsoft is using SignalR for Blazor that is new.

Comment: Also, if you read the answers to that thread they all say Websockets is not obsolete. In the future you may start seeing libraries take advantage of Websockets over HTTP/2 and start using Webtransport with HTTP/3.