# Periodically calling a function, stack growing indefinite

Tags: javascript, settimeout, ajax-polling

I have the following JavaScript code and noticed the stack is growing indefinitely.

https://jsfiddle.net/uok7vz9b/

```js
(function () {
  async function poll() {
    try {
        // await fetch ...
    } catch (err) {
      console.error("Error: ", err);
    } finally {
      console.trace();
      start();
    }
  }

  function start() {
    setTimeout(poll, 2000);
  }

  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", poll, {once: true});
})();
```

First output is:

```
console.trace() _display:118:15
    poll https://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/?editor_console=true:118
    (Async: EventListener.handleEvent)
    <anonymous> https://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/?editor_console=true:127
    <anonymous> https://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/?editor_console=true:128
```

Second output:

```
console.trace() _display:118:15
    poll https://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/?editor_console=true:118
    (Async: setTimeout handler)
    start https://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/?editor_console=true:124
    poll https://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/?editor_console=true:119
    (Async: EventListener.handleEvent)
    <anonymous> https://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/?editor_console=true:127
    <anonymous> https://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/?editor_console=true:128
```

... and so on.

I don't really understand why, because I though `setTimeout` does not block and just starts a new timer. So I expected the `poll` function to finish, and then it is fired again with a clean stack.

I have looked around and not really found any good examples for *"execute function once on page load and then periodically"*. I don't want to use `setInterval` because long running AJAX calls could then exceed the timeout. But the timeout should rather be the *minimum* time between two calls of `poll`.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter — I'm just voting to close — but, can you post your code here? It's fine to link to a Fiddle if that's helpful, but that should be *in addition* to posting it here, not *instead* of posting it here. (For one thing, Fiddles aren't readable on the same range of devices as StackOverflow.)

Comment: I also see this happening. If you were to repeat the code in your fiddle as part of the question, and the output that is giving you concern, then I suspect that this might encourage better participation.

Comment: Thanks. I have updated the question accordingly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running an operation periodically when the length of operation is not known](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62086948/running-an-operation-periodically-when-the-length-of-operation-is-not-known)

Comment: I've voted to reopen because question was edited to provide debugging details, clearly demonstrates something that might be problematic with a clear repro using relatively idiomatic code, and there don't appear to be other questions asked on this subject. It's a good question.

Comment: @spender I tried to close it as duplicate, but it already had two "no debugging details" votes on it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a result of [async stack traces](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/async-call-stack/). I have no idea if it's possible to blow the async stack or whether there are measures in the browser to limit the depth of the async stack preventing overflow/leaks.

While the following code does the same thing:

```js
(function() {
  const delay = (duration) => new Promise(r => setTimeout(() => r(), duration))
  async function poll() {
    for (;;) {
      try {
        // await fetch ...
      } catch (err) {
        console.error("Error: ", err);
      } finally {
        console.trace();
      }
      await delay(2000)
    }

  }


  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", poll, {
    once: true
  });
})();
```

It does not add to the async stack.

Comment: @Micha [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68375903/how-does-v8-reconstruct-async-stacktraces-with-requestanimationframe) provides a glimpse of what's happening here. Opening devtools makes an internal call to [setAsyncCallStackDepth](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Debugger/#method-setAsyncCallStackDepth), suggesting that the depth of the stack is limited, and that this won't happen unless devtools is opened.

Comment: The async stack is not real. It is there only for the dev tools to print useful stack traces on errors. Unlike the real call stack blowing the async stack will not cause any issue to your program. You'll only lose tracibility in error messages.