# how to implement “server push ” on apache-php-mysql machine?

Tags: javascript

here is the question:
    when one user upload something to the server(apache).
the server will " push " the request data to all the users .
  and I don't want to use "ajax" or javascript "timeout reload"。
It costs a lot 
  so, Is there any javascript lib can implement the "server push" technology?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [WebSockets](http://www.websocket.org/). I, for one, am using long pooling through XMPP, but I think WebSockets looks promising (maybe my next product version will use WebSockets).

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253683/what-browsers-support-html5-websocket-api) StackOverflow question for some details regarding WebSockets support.

Implementation wise, you could use a combination of [Socket.IO](http://socket.io/) and [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) to achieve the WebSockets "server push". An example of someone doing this can be found [here](http://www.gianlucaguarini.com/blog/?p=272).