# Should i use Websocket module in Apache?

Tags: apache, module, apache2, websocket

I'm trying to integrate the websocket into existing application.

Based on my search, i found a websocket module to do this, but it isn't updated yet. 
https://github.com/disconnect/apache-websocket.

Any chance that the module will be included in Apache ?

Also i found in StackOverflow conversation that Apache httpd wasn't design to maintain persistent connection, is that true ? 
[Using WebSocket on Apache server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11334320/using-websocket-on-apache-server)

Should continue using Apache websocket module or using separate websocket server ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last time I checked, the websocket module for Apache was forwarding any incomming WS connection to a shared library which you have to implement yourself.

When you have an application which listens to normal sockets and you want it to be accessible through websockets, [Websockify](https://github.com/kanaka/websockify) could be your solution.