# how can apache server can support websockets?

Tags: apache, websocket

I'm new to websockets and playing with servers is not my thing. I'm using "clasic" Apache http server 2.2.22 and Geoserver on my project. Is there an easy-to-use (and install) patch or module for Apache, so it can support websockets? I'm not looking for a stand-alone server, because, IMHO, 3 servers on the same project is too much. I'm looking for a newbie-friendly patch. Any suggestions?

I'm searching the internet for some days and I could not figure out what is what. 
How about jwebsockets? Does this works nicely with Apache?
Any other suggestions?

Thank you

Comment: Find the recommended patch and similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11334320/using-websocket-on-apache-server

Comment: @DaShaun I already checked this question. To be honest phpwebsocket seems like a hack, not a documented patch. As for phpws and apache-websocket their instalation guidelines are way too confusing for my level. About Pusher, I dont want to use a third-party app. Bottom line, its not them, its me, I dont want to be disrespectfull to the developers

Comment: Geoserver can deploy into Jetty or Tomcat, both of with contain websocket support.

Comment: @jessemcconnell I think Geoserver is based on Jetty.Anyway, I thought that maybe Geoserver can handle websockets, but I can not think of anything in particular to implement. Apache contains all my html files and Geoserver some maps etc. How can geoserver act like websockets handler? Any ideas?

Comment: websockets are basically a http connection, upgraded to a websocket connection brokered through a servlet...once that is setup then control is based to whatever is going to handle things, in jetty9 it can just be an annotated pojo.  what that traffic is is up to you... imo SPDY would be more bang for your buck with what you're serving