# Phonegap Application check the status for each and every record in every 30 second

Tags: android, cordova, mobile, iso

I am developing PhoneGap application for the first time and I am confused how to develop this application.

I would like to fetch records from another site/service and display the fetched information in my app. Then I have to check the status of each record every 30 seconds. So can anyone tell me how I can do this? I think if I send AJAX request to the server for every record then the server will get lots of requests and will slow down.

I am implementing this application for both Android and iOS platforms.

1. Is this possible in PhoneGap?
2. Do I have to user a WebSocket library or nodejs for this?
3. Is WebSocket supported in all platforms, like iOS and Android?

if there any easy way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible in `Phonegap`. Use the following method in the `javascript` file or `<script>` tag:

```
 setInterval(
     function () 
 { //place the method that you want to implement 

 }, 30000); // for every 30 seconds it will be called
```

the `setInterval()` will be called for every 30 seconds

Comment: but i have to call for each and every record so for every record setinterval is not feasible.

Comment: Why not check the status of every record with a single request and return a list of all the records that have changed.

Comment: but if there is lots of records then it will take lots of time.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes it is possible in PhoneGap platform as the application is based
   on JavaScript which allows AJAX requests.
2. WebSocket implementation would be faster but you will need to limit support to only iOS.
3. WebSocket API is not widely supported. See [What browsers support HTML5 WebSocket API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253683/what-browsers-support-html5-websocket-api)

My suggestion would be to batch your requests to return information about multiple records at the same time with a single request. See a simple example below:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "get-record-info.php",
  data: { record-ids: "1,2,3,4"} 

}).done(function (msg) {

  //This is the JSON message received from the service.
  alert( "Data Saved: " + msg ); 

});
```

Hope this helps!