# socket.io - iPad always gets a timeout, although it is connected

Tags: javascript, ipad, node.js, socket.io

I have a simple chat app with node.js and socket.io:
[tutorial full code](http://www.adityaravishankar.com/2011/10/nowjs-node-js-tutorial-creating-multi-room-chat-server/)

It works perfectly if the clients enters the website from a PC. If the client uses a IPad (ios 5.1/ latest Chrome / safari) it only works sometimes.  Most of the time the webpage is loaded, then the iPad connects, but it takes so long that the server closes the connection. Then the iPad gets a new connection, but cannot really initialize a session. It periodically is disconnected and tries to reconnect again.

Here the protocoll of socket.io:
[image]

client code:

```
socket = io.connect(http://42.58.240.427:4000);
socket.on('connect', function(){

  send('init');
});
```

server code:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

socket.on('init', function(){

    console.log("Good morning new User");
});


socket.on('disconnect', function(){

    requesthandler['disconnect'](socket, io);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing it is due to browser websocket support. iOS Safari (5.0-5.1) browser implements an older websocket protocol (Hixie-76). So it only supports websocket partially. See the websocket support [chart](http://caniuse.com/websockets).

When you say it works sometimes, most likely it is falling back to long-polling. It can be connected this way but it can have timeout problems. See the differences between websocket and long-polling in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10028770/html5-websocket-vs-long-short-polling). The reconnect happens by default. But timeout will happen.

So it is best to upgrade the browser to latest version which fully supports websockets.

Sources: [What browsers support HTML5 WebSocket API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253683/what-browsers-support-html5-websocket-api/2700609)

Comment: do you know how to get a browser that supports websockets for iPad1? The latest Chrome for iPad1 is doing long polling according to your explanation?

Comment: I don't have any experience on mobile chrome version and it is relatively new to iOS platform. I could not find any ways to make it work. Which version for chrome did you try?

Comment: @poppel chrome for ipad is a chrome wrapper around the same engine that safari uses