# NodeJS and Primus.io WebSocket opening handshake was canceled

Tags: node.js, proxy, websocket, primus

I'm trying to connect with Primus using websockets:

`WebSocket connection to 'wss://dev.dylaan.nl/primus/?_primuscb=1417355606238-6' failed: WebSocket opening handshake was canceled`

My NodeJS script:

```
var express     = require("express")
,   fs          = require("fs")
,   path        = require("path")
,   moment      = require("moment")
,   Primus      = require("primus")
,   compression = require("compression")
,   app         = express()
,   http        = require("http").createServer(app)
,   jsp         = require("uglify-js").parser
,   pro         = require("uglify-js").uglify
,   primus      = new Primus(http, { transformer: "websockets" });
```

Client:

```
var primus      = new Primus("wss://dev.dylaan.nl")
```

I'm new to this kind of stuff, but I don't know whats wrong now, I have read the docs from Primus, I have also tried to Google but I can find the answer.

When I change to protocol to `ws` instead of `wss` I get the error

`Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 426`

`http 426 may mean that you are trying to connect with an unsupported websocket protocol version`

`Also, if you are connecting through a proxy, the proxy may remove the "upgrade" header from the request since it is marked as "connection" header. Switch to WSS:// to prevent that.`

@
[Unexpected response code: 426 with PhanthomJS Websocket client/ROSLIB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23123932/unexpected-response-code-426-with-phanthomjs-websocket-client-roslib)

Well, my VPS is behind a ngnix reversed proxy. I have no access to that.So thats why I'm using wss.

Demo: http://dev.dylaan.nl/play

Can somebody help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you've configured your nginx server incorrectly and that it's blocking WebSocket connections causing a 400 error to be returned. See http://nginx.com/blog/websocket-nginx/ on how you can configure the server to allow websocket connections.

If you cannot get your host/vps to verify that WebSocket connects are allowed you can turn off WebSockets completely in Primus by supplying the option `{ websocket: false }` in the client code:

```
new Primus("http://dev.dylaan.nl", { websocket: false })
```

I also noticed you used `wss/ws` instead of `http` which Primus requires, we will rewrite the HTTP based url in to the correct format automatically.

Comment: I'm using version 2.4.10 of Primus and client library accepts ws:// urls.