# Upgrade Required ( node.js )

Tags: javascript, node.js, webrtc

I made the signaling server by using webRTC.
This is why I made the signaling server(signaling.js).

What should I do to solve this problem?

・signaling.js

```
"use strict"; 


let WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server;
let port = 3001;
let wsServer = new WebSocketServer({ port: port });
console.log('websocket server start. port=' + port);

wsServer.on('connection', function(ws) {
  console.log('-- websocket connected --');
  ws.on('message', function(message) {
    wsServer.clients.forEach(function each(client) {
      if (isSame(ws, client)) {
        console.log('- skip sender -');
      }
      else {
        client.send(message);
      }
    });
  });
});

function isSame(ws1, ws2) {
  // -- compare object --
  return (ws1 === ws2);
}  let wsUrl = 'ws://localhost:3001/';
  let ws = new WebSocket(wsUrl);
  ws.onopen = function(evt) {
    console.log('ws open()');
  };
  ws.onerror = function(err) {
    console.error('ws onerror() ERR:', err);
  };

  ws.onmessage = function(evt) {
   console.log('ws onmessage() data:', evt.data);
   let message = JSON.parse(evt.data);
   if (message.type === 'offer') {
     // -- got offer ---
     console.log('Received offer ...');
     textToReceiveSdp.value = message.sdp;
     let offer = new RTCSessionDescription(message);
     setOffer(offer);
   }
   else if (message.type === 'answer') {
     // --- got answer ---
     console.log('Received answer ...');
     textToReceiveSdp.value = message.sdp;
     let answer = new RTCSessionDescription(message);
     setAnswer(answer);
   }
 };

 function sendSdp(sessionDescription) {
    console.log('---sending sdp ---');

    textForSendSdp.value = sessionDescription.sdp;
    /*--- テキストエリアをハイライトするのを止める
    textForSendSdp.focus();
    textForSendSdp.select();
    ----*/

    // --- シグナリングサーバーに送る ---
    let message = JSON.stringify(sessionDescription);
    console.log('sending SDP=' + message);
    ws.send(message);
  }
```

When I load the "signaling.js", I set the node.js.
After that, I access signaling.js.
However, It listed upgrade required.

I searched how to upgrade node.js.

I tried

```
Linux/Mac:

The module n makes version-management easy:

sudo npm install n -g
sudo n 0.12.2
For the latest stable version:

sudo n stable
For the latest version:

sudo n latest
```

after this, I accessed signaling.js

```
/signaling.js:26
  let ws = new WebSocket(wsUrl);
               ^

ReferenceError: WebSocket is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Desktop/webRTC/signaling.js:26:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:509:3
```

Comment: You need to `require` the package containing `WebSocket` before you can use it.

Comment: how do I get the package in WebSocket?

Comment: Looking at the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws) I think you just have to do `let WebSocket = require('ws');` before trying to initialize the `WebSocket`.

Comment: Thanks @BlazeSahlzen.
I try the above. but it listed "Update Required":(

Comment: Can you please show the new error message?

Comment: this is new error.


Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 426 (Upgrade Required)

Comment: Have you successfully updated node? What is the current version?

Comment: @BlazeSahlzen
I have checked the version now.
I think the version of node is latest, v.6.8.1.
So, I don't know why it list "update required"

Comment: For the 'Update Required' error, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/20584128/1025222

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to create a WebSockets client and server in the same script.

```
/signaling.js:26
  let ws = new WebSocket(wsUrl);
               ^

ReferenceError: WebSocket is not defined
```

This error occurs because you've forgotten to define the `WebSocket` variable at the top of your file:

```
var WebSocket = require('ws');
```

Since you want to use the same methods as you would inside a web browser, (`ws.onopen`, `ws.onerror`, ...), I'd recommend you to use the `websocket` package instead, with the `w3cwebsocket` module.

```
var WebSocket = require('websocket').w3cwebsocket;
```

After discussing the issue inside the comments, I would like to suggest that you remove completely the `'ws'` package and use `'websocket'` instead.

```
var WebSocketServer = require('websocket').server;
```

Instead of creating a WebSocket server directly, you should create a HTTP server first:

```
var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    console.log((new Date()) + ' Received request for ' + request.url);
    response.writeHead(404);
    response.end();
});
server.listen(8080, function() {
    console.log((new Date()) + ' Server is listening on port 8080');
});
```

Then attach the WebSocket server on it:

```
wsServer = new WebSocketServer({
    httpServer: server,
    autoAcceptConnections: false
});
```

A new connection will trigger the `request` event, you'll have to accept the incoming connection:

```
// wsServer.on('connection', function(ws) {
wsServer.on('request', function(request) {
    var ws = request.accept();
```

You'll be able to retrieve the clients list with the `connections` property.

```
// wsServer.clients.forEach(function each(client) {
wsServer.connections.forEach(function each(client) {
```

Comment: thanks, I tried the above. However, there is new error;(

node signaling.js
module.js:471
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'websocket'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)

Comment: I added 

var WebSocket = require('websocket').w3cwebsocket;

the top of file,"singnaling.js".

Comment: You need to install the `websocket` package, try to run the following command in a terminal: `npm install --save websocket`

Comment: Ok, thanks, I tried npm install --save websocket

however , there is error, the same one " upgrade required".

so I keep tryng your reference" stackoverflow.com/a/20584128/1025222 "

Comment: Try to replace `let WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server;` with `let WebSocketServer = require('websocket').server;`. I've never encountered that error before, it's really weird actually.

Comment: I have tried replacing let WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server; with let WebSocketServer = require('websocket').server;

this is new error.

node signaling.js 

/Users/sawamuratakahiro/node_modules/websocket/lib/WebSocketServer.js:144
        throw new Error('You must specify an httpServer on which to mount the WebSocket server.');
        ^

Error: You must specify an httpServer on which to mount the WebSocket server.

Comment: For that one, you should try to create an HTTP server and attach the websocket server on it, read more at https://www.npmjs.com/package/websocket#server-example

Comment: ummm....
so difficult. I don't know how to change this script about HTTP serer and attach the websocket server on it .

Comment: Alright, I'm updating my answer to give a general advice on your code.

Comment: @tk08 Here it is !

Comment: Thanks for your precious time, Axel.
I really appreciate you, I retry this program by checking your explanation.
you're great Engineer and great man!