# Is pywebsocket good for a production environment?

Tags: python, sockets, websocket, mod-pywebsocket

Is it a good idea to use **pywebsocket** in a production environment, since their [google developer page](http://code.google.com/p/pywebsocket/) states ...

> pywebsocket is intended for testing or experimental purposes.

Moreover what would the specific drawbacks of using it be?

- Are there performance drawbacks?
- Is it not stable or unsecure in a certain way?
- ...

Since [Mozilla](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/d322a1c8537e/testing/mochitest/pywebsocket) as well as Google use it to test their websocket implementations, and it was suggested (for production) in many SO threads, I thought it to be a pretty stable basis until I read the docs.

Or am I misinterpeting something, and it is just meant to be *especially* helpful for testing, as well as suitable in production?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research it becomes clear, that `pywebsockets` was developed for [testing browser implementations](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pywebsocket/qmhFubyEkvQ). It has (at least) the drawbacks of [being neither secure nor scalable](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pywebsocket/VgA8oTh7FYo).

So in short: **It is not suitable to be used in production environment!**

As stated above it is still a great tool for testing your client side implementation of websockets, probably even "the best" one for that, since the websocket implementations of Chrome as well as Firefox,... are being tested with it.

As alternatives for production in python you could look at:

- [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/export/29073/branches/websocket-4173-2/doc/web/howto/websocket.xhtml)
- [Tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/)
- [Gist](https://gist.github.com/jkp/3136208)
- [websockify](https://github.com/kanaka/websockify)
- [Autobahn](http://autobahn.ws/)

For a list of tools for other programming languages have a look at [this SO wiki answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253683/what-browsers-support-html5-websocket-api/2700609#2700609)