# How to implement server-updates-listener in client side

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, observers

I have a theoretical question regarding design patterns.
I would like my client to receive events from my server side, let's say when the user receives a new message in chat.

Let's assume we are running JavaScript on the client side.
One way to implement this would be to send a request from the client to the server asking `'Are there any updates?'` periodically. This is inefficient since we will be sending too many redundant requests when there are no updates available.

Is there a way to listen to updates from the server side only when there are such. For example implementing a receiver/listener in the client? If this can't be done with JavaScript how else would you do it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few solutions here:

1. Have your AJAX requests run in a timed loop. While not real time, it has properties similar to a real time application.

   ```
   var requestLoop = setInterval(function(){
     //HTTP Request to update data here
   }, 60000);
   ```
2. [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API). This is specifically what they were developed for, "With this API, you can send messages to a server and receive event-driven responses without having to poll the server for a reply."
   **Note: There are browser support issues w/ Edge/IE**

Additional: [Writing WebSockets for JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications)

Stackoverflow on WebSocket support: [What browsers support HTML5 WebSocket API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253683/what-browsers-support-html5-websocket-api)

Comment: Thank you. WebSockets is what I was looking for :)