# InValid Frame header on Websocket using node.js

Tags: websocket, socket.io, ngrok

I get the following error in my chrome console.

> **websocket.js:111 WebSocket connection to 'ws://c7f2053b.ngrok.io/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket' failed: Invalid frame header**

In my firefox i get this

> **The connection to ws://c7f2053b.ngrok.io/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=h1U3iQ9b3INSkg9xAAAC was interrupted while the page was loading**.

Is there anyway to clear this issue please suggest me ...

Answer (score 0):

Please check 

 1) **Chrome and Firefox versions**. Older versions might not have full support for WebSockets
[What browsers support HTML5 WebSocket API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253683/what-browsers-support-html5-websocket-api)

 2) **Test Basic code :**: Try with regular JavaScript Code first and see if connection is establishing:-

```
websocket = new WebSocket(URL);
websocket.onopen = function(evt) {
    alert("Connected...");
    websocket.send(message);
websocket.onmessage = function(evt) {
    alert(evt.data);
};
websocket.onclose = function(evt) {
    alert(evt.data);
};
websocket.onerror = function(evt) {
  alert(evt.data);
};
```

Comment: thankyou for ur help .. its works fine .. before i used chrome and mozila browsers only . now i check this into internet explorer now its works fine . Thankyou so much ....